# Adding a new attribute in Request object using lombok Builder

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

### Background

I want to add one more attribute `TemplateId` to the `Request` object. Currently the `Request` object is constructed in the function `transform` using builder like below:

```
public class DocFactory { 

ModuleProvider<Collection<Scenario>> dollarScenarioProvider;

public Request transform(String requestId, Product product) {
    Request.RequestBuilder.builder = Request.builder();

    BiFunction<Throwable, Runnable, Throwable> handler = (e, runnable) -> {
       if (e == null) {
          runnable.run();
          return null;
       } else {
          Log.error ("Failed to process DocumentRequestModule(())", requestId, e.getCause);
          return e.getCause);

    String errorMessage = Stream.of(dollarScenarioProvider.getAsync(product)
                         .handle((result, e) -> handler.apply(e, () ->                                                             
                           builder.scenarioDollar(result)))))
                                .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .map(Throwable::getMessage)
                                ...
}}
```

For the `getAsync` method in `ModuleProvider`, it's defined like so:

```
public interface ModuleProvider<R> {

default CompletableFuture<R> getAsync (Product product) {
     return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(get(product));
}

//other methods omitted
```

### My questions:

1. The attribute I want to add in `Request` is `TemplateId`, which is a string. This string will be returned by a function `getTemplateId` (which takes in the argument `Product product` and returns a String). It seems like maybe I should do something like:

```
TemplateIdProvider.getAsync(product)
                         .handle((result, e) -> handler.apply(e, () ->                                                             
                           builder.TemplateId(result)))))
```

But where should I put the function `getTemplateId`?

1. I don't exactly understand what this code is doing. Is it related to Factory Pattern?  I know the code that I shared is trying to construct a Request using builder, but the way is it done (using `handler` & ModuleProvider, ... seems obscure to me , could you please share with me your insight on why it would be done this way?

```
TemplateIdProvider.getAsync(product)
                         .handle((result, e) -> handler.apply(e, () ->                                                             
                           builder.TemplateId(result)))))
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: In your code, where you have `Request.builder()`, what `Request` is that? If that is from your own project / you have control over the source, simply add your TempateId there. If you don't - you can't do this - lombok just helps you by replacing boilerplate with an annotation, it has nothing to do with modifying code beyond your control.